# where can I find a good enough default config to compile the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i want to compile a custom linux kernel for myself. because i dont know every option of kernel therefore i am looking for a good default config for start.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the repository of the Linux distribution you are using, they often have a generic or a huge kernel `.config`, those are the "best choices".

Answer (score 4):

You should check out [KernelCheck](http://kcheck.sourceforge.net/). It's basically an app that will help you figure out what kernel options are worth tweaking for your particular system. It will also automatically download, compile and install the selected kernel for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a good running kernel that has builtin support for stored configuration (i.e. `/proc/config.gz` exists), then you could copy that kernel configuration and use it as a starting point:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > /path/to/kernel/source/.config
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Linux kernel source tree, type `make help` and look for the lines that include `defconfig`. Default configurations for various platforms are typically included here. Once you find the one that matches your platform, type, for example `make defconfig` to get your default `.config` file. For example, to build on a Nexus S, I use `make herring_defconfig`. (herring is, I guess, the code name for the Nexus S hardware, which can incidentally be found if you look at `/proc/cpuinfo` on the Nexus S)

If you are not building for x86 (for example, like in my case, if you are building for Android) be sure to remember to export `ARCH` (for example, `export ARCH=arm` before running `make`). Otherwise, `make help` will not show the correct defconfig targets for the architecture you want to build.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in a while but aren't there sane defaults in the config dialogs?

Comment: no default config dosnt seem so good. some debug modes are enable and other things.

Comment: The default config should be pretty darn close to good, unless you need something specific?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I feel compelled to add http://kernel-seeds.org/ as a very viable option for a starting point to compile a fitting custom kernel -- as there are seeds for the vanilla sources, even if you are not on gentoo.